# Dots indicator for ViewPager2 doesn't show

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager2, indicator

I'm using simple ViewPager2 with static number od pages and I want to add dots indicator into it. I found many samples how to do it and I already have working indicator in the bottom of page using **TabLayouMediator**, but I can't see the dots. When I tap to the place where the indicator should be, it switches pages and effect of button click are visible. Anyway I cannot see the default and active dot image. The dot indicator is used from tutorial on stackoverflow.

Since the indicator can switch pages, I think that the **TabLayouMediator** is implemented correctly. Also I think that the indicator isn't covered by any layout, because I can use it and I see tap effects. Regarding this, I think that the problem is in TabLayout, but I cannot identify it.

Below are my codes. Thank you very much for any help.

**activity.java**

```
TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        TabLayoutMediator tabLayoutMediator = new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager2, true, new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) { }
        });
        tabLayoutMediator.attach();
```

**activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/TutorialSmartphone_Cl_Header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/TutorialSmartphone_Gl_Header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_end="30dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/TutorialSmartphone_Iv_Logo"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/TutorialSmartphone_Gl_Header"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/TutorialSmartphone_Sw_ShowNextTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:scrollbarSize="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/TutorialSmartphone_Gl_Header"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TutorialSmartphone_Tv_ShowNextTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="showNextTime"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/TutorialSmartphone_Gl_Header" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/TutorialSmartphone_Rl_ViewerPage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/TutorialSmartphone_Rl_Buttons"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TutorialSmartphone_Cl_Header"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/TutorialSmartphone_Rl_Buttons">

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/TutorialSmartphone_Vp_Text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/TutorialSmartphone_Rl_Buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/TutorialSmartphone_Iv_Prev"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:onClick="prevPage"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:rotation="180"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/triangle" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/TutorialSmartphone_Iv_Next"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:onClick="nextPage"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/triangle" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/TutorialSmartphone_Bt_Close"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:onClick="nextPage"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:text="closeVerb"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/TutorialSmartphone_Iv_Next"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/TutorialSmartphone_Iv_Prev"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**tab_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_dot"
        android:state_selected="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/default_dot"/>
</selector>
```

**selected_dot.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="8dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="@color/black"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**default_dot.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="8dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="@color/gray"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: I copied above code that you shared. Made only necessary additions to make it work. And works for me on api 17 and api 24. I am able to see and use the dots. One thing I can think of check your colors are not transparent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Sozsoy. Colors color/black and color/gray are defined in color.xml as '#000000' and '#DDDDDD', so it should be fine.
I am testing it API 24 and API 29 and it's same one both devices, even on emulated API 29 device. Is it possible that indicator from TabLayoutMediator is over all layouts, but the visual part of it is below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after two weeks I found the problem. In styles.xml I deleted `<item name="android:background">@color/white</item>` and everything is fine now. Thanks to @Sozsoy I tried to make new project with my code and compare what could cause troubles.